# Escape / handling "special typefaces" single quote in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are some special way to put quotation mark (single and doubles), how do I escape or anyway to handle both of them in JavaScript or Jquery.

My current effort is

```
text.replace(/(['"])/g, "\\$1");
```

But that only help to handle `'` and `"`

For some cases, user use special quotation mark (that I don't even know how do they have that quote) with `’s` and `“Ang”`

```
1. Peter’s book 
2. Mike's book

1. "Comment"
2. “Post”
```

Comment: use \ (backslash) before character you want escape

Comment: Try as `/([\'\"])/g`

Comment: your approach is correct, just keep adding symbols that you want to escape to your pattern

Comment: Have you tried something like this: `text.replace(/(['"’“”])/g, "\\$1");`?

Comment: Are you talking about smart quotes? Angled quotes that applications like Word and Slack replace ascii quotes with? If so you should be able to copy the chars from a Word doc and paste them into your code

Comment: @Artur I need to do it programmatically

Comment: I have no idea what you want accomplish.

Comment: @david.lucky I know my approach will work, but for this case, it's not even a character on your keyboard. so I'm not quite sure do I need to use Html Numeric code, or is there anyway I can detect them

Comment: @Artur simple that I have a text box, allow user to key in themself. Error will appear if user use these characters

Comment: @acdcjunior thanks i will try this effort

Comment: @Spangen Thanks, I don't know it called smart quotes. Just do some research. I will try those approach

Comment: What characters are allowed in text box? A-z0-9_- ?

Comment: I think [these](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html) are the things that you need to escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a [wide range of](https://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html) [quotes](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html). You can add them to the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) of the regex like below. Either directly:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("pre").text(function(_, text) {
    return text.replace(/(['"‘’“”`´])/g, "\\$1");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
- 'straight single'
- "straight double"
- ‘opening/closing single’
- “opening/closing double”
- `Grave`
- ´Grave´
</pre>
<button>Click to escape</button>
```

Or escaped:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("pre").text(function(_, text) {
    return text.replace(/(['"\u2018\u2019\u201C\u201D`´])/g, "\\$1");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
- 'straight single'
- "straight double"
- ‘opening/closing single’
- “opening/closing double”
- `Grave`
- ´Grave´
</pre>
<button>Click to escape</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the link, as well as 2nd method, so I don't have to copy the special characters everytime